# Why is this a syntax error? Is there a way of returning both the variables when using onscreen click?

Tags: python, syntax-error, global-variables

This is a python program in 3.10 and I need a separate x and y variable to use for my function which so I can place the noughts /crosses where they need to go. I have tried returning it as one two then split later but it doesn't actually store anything. my plan was then to set them a s global variables but it says it is a syntax error. I am still learning to code and don't understand why. also if there is a way of returning them what is it.

```
def which(hx,hy):
    if (hx > -54 and hx < -21) and (hy >43 and hy < 75):
        place=0
    elif (hx > -22 and hx < 19) and (hy >43 and hy < 75):
        place=1
    elif (hx > 20 and hx < -54) and (hy >43 and hy < 75):
        place=2
    elif (hx > -54 and hx < -21) and (hy > 3 and hy < 41):
        place=3
    elif (hx > -22 and hx < 19) and (hy >3 and hy < 41):
        place=4
    elif (hx > 20 and hx < -54) and (hy >3 and hy < 41):
        place=5
    elif (hx > -54 and hx < -21) and (hy > -37 and hy < 1):
        place=6
    elif (hx > -22 and hx < 19) and (hy > -37 and hy < 1):
        place=7
    elif (hx > 20 and hx < -54) and (hy > -37 and hy < 1):
        place=8
    return place

def seperate(x,y):
    global cx = x # this is the problem(it highlights the = red)
    global cy = y

onscreenclick(seperate)
print(cx)
print(cy)
h=which(cx,cy)
n(h)
```

Comment: It’s difficult to tell because of the formatting issues, but did you mean: print(cx) ?

Comment: that was just an issue with formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def seperate(x,y):
    global cx = x # this is the problem(it highlights the = red)
    global cy = y
```

Change to

```
def seperate(x,y):
    global cx 
    cx= x # this is the problem(it highlights the = red)
    global cy
    cy = y
```

You are declaring a variable as global and assigning it a value at the Same time. Python wants you to declare variables global, then you can assign values to it.

[W3school-Python global variables](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp)

Comment: Hi @nothingcode1, I believe my answer has worked for you. Do mark as "Accepted Answer". Thanks